# Loading Text file to HTML textarea from mobile phone storage

Tags: javascript, html, text, io

I am writing an app for mobile phones using HTML5, Javascript and CSS. One part of the app should allow the user to load a text file present the phone's local storage on to a text area provided on that page. My questions are:

1. How do I create a file dialog box to ask user to select the txt file. (Is it possible?)
2. I read something about PHP etc to load files but I have no experience in it. Is there like a code snippet that I could use to load text file? Can Javascript, jquery mobile has something to do this?
3. Once I load it into the textarea, I want to edit it and save it again.

It would be helpful if someone can throw some light on this or direct me towards some resource where I can learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

Local I/O is never allowed directly, for what should be fairly obvious security reasons. You need to set up an `<input type="file">` form to do this, but I'm not sure how those behave on a mobile platform. I'm sure that that would very between platforms. Assuming a successful file upload and transmission to your editing area, saving back to storage would require a file download you would have to initiate, and which the user could choose to accept or ignore.

You use the words "local storage" and your tags include HTML 5, so there are additional options. You can look in to the [LocalStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) API, which allows you to store larger amounts of data which you can then retrieve, allow editing on, and save. This is controlled by the browser to eliminate security issues. There is also the [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/), which allows reading files. I believe this is read-only, however, (again for security) and may not be what you are looking for.